# Идентификация асинхронных запросов-ответов

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, асинхронность

У меня, наконец, получилось сделать асинхронные запросы-ответы. Осталась одна проблема - идентификация запросов.

```
    private void fixedAsynchronousTesting() throws Exception {

            ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.altDN.add("CN=Test org1, SERIALNUMBER=1111111111");
            this.altDN.add("CN=Test org2, SERIALNUMBER=2222222222");

            String userPassword;
            if (this.username != null && this.password != null) {
                userPassword = this.username + ":" + this.password;
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException("Нет логина и/или пароля.");
            }

            AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = Dsl.asyncHttpClient();

            this.apiUrl = apiUrl + "/pkcs10/getPKCS10Cert";
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonRequest = certificateCreateAsyncRequest();
                this.requestId++;
                requestResponse(this.apiUrl, threads, userPassword, asyncHttpClient, jsonRequest, this.requestId);
                log.info("UserAsynchronous " + this.userId + ": Запрос " + this.requestId + " отправлен.");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }

   private JSONObject certificateCreateAsyncRequest() {
        this.keyName = getRandomName();
        this.dn = getDN(this.keyName);
        CertificateCreateAsyncRequest newUser = new CertificateCreateAsyncRequest(this.dn, this.keyName, this.keyPass, this.template, this.useHSM, this.internalHSMKey, this.altDN);
        return newUser.formRequest();
    }

    private void requestResponse(String apiUrl, ExecutorService threads, String userPassword, AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient, JSONObject jsonRequest, int requestId) {
        Request request = Dsl.post(apiUrl)
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
                .setBody(jsonRequest.toString().getBytes())
                .build();

        ListenableFuture<Response> listenableFuture = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request);
        listenableFuture.addListener(() -> {
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = listenableFuture.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (response != null) {
                log.info("UserAsynchronous " + this.userId + ": Ответ " + this.requestId + " получен.");
            }
        }, threads);
    }
```

Код, приведенный выше, дает такой результат:

> 2019-07-04 17:00:33 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос
>   1 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:33 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 2 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:33 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 3 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:33 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 4
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:33 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 5 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:33 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 6 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 7 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 8
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 9 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 10 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 11 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 12
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 13 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 14 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:34 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 15 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 16
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 16 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 17 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 17 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос
>   18 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 18 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 19 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 19 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос
>   20 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 21 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 22 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 23
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 23 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:35 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 24 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:35 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 24 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос
>   25 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 26 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 26 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 27
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 27 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 28 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 29
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 29 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 30 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 31
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 31 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 32 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 33
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:36 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 34 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 34 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 35 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 35
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 36 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 36 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 36 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 37
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous
>   1: Запрос 38 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 38 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 39 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 40
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 40 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 41 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 42
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 42 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:37 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 43 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:37 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 43 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   43 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 43 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 44 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 45
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 45 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 46 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 46 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос
>   47 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:98 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 48 отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 48 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 49
>   отправлен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 49 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:98 - UserAsynchronous 1: Запрос 50 отправлен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:38 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:39 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 -
>   UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO 
>   MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен. 2019-07-04
>   17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ 50 получен.
>   2019-07-04 17:00:40 INFO  MainAPITest:126 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ
>   50 получен.

Из него видно, что система работает асинхронно (блокирующий метод response = listenableFuture.get(); блокирует поток в отдельном thread, только для того, чтобы вывести информацию из ответа). Но мой requestId обновляется для все программы, а не для конкретного запроса.... Надо сделать так, чтобы оно отправило запросы 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,16 а когда поступает ответ от сервера, видело, что это ответ 1,2,3, а не начиная с 16, до которого уже отправка успела дойти.

Comment: вы используете общую переменную requestId более того, ответы могут приходить не в том порядке, в каком вы их отправили, вам нужно посылать id в запросе и читать их

Comment: Правильно ли, что в таком случае надо внести изменения в код сервера, чтобы он это id принимал, а затем отправлял назад с запросом, или это необязательно? Или можно как-то "привязать" идентификатор к запросу, не внося изменений в сервер?

Comment: Добавьте header к запросу и прочитайте его, когда принимаете

Comment: Достает null из ответа)     2019-07-04 17:47:30 INFO  MainAPITest:128 - UserAsynchronous 1: Ответ null получен.      Ладно, попробую видоизменить код сервера, чтобы id учитывал.